# How to activate a channel with Discord.py

Tags: discord.py

When a channel is created in Discord the channel is automatically highlighted/activated:
[image]

However in code using Discord.py when I create a channel the channel is not activated.

```
await guild.create_text_channel("new-test-channel")
```

I can get the channel and send a message but that's not really what i need to do.
I have some interactions with the GUI so I need it to be highlighted and active.  Is there anyway I can activate it, highlight it, "grab it", whatever you want to call it so long as it's active?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no highlight or active step for bot (Either `commands.Context` or `discord.Interaction`). If you don't specify channel, bot's corresponding response will be sent in the same channel as you called the command.
You can always get the channel by `ctx.channel` or `interaction.channel` (depends on you use message command or application/slash command)
If you want to switch to the channel you just created, you can get the channel simply by `new_test_channel = await guild.create_text_channel("new-test-channel")`, and then do relevants action based on this variable.

Comment: Can you explain this please? application/slash command